# JVM Bug with JDWP

Tags: java, jdwp

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6339385) from Sun indicating a problem with certain Java versions and enabling a JDWP port. But that bug report doesn't indicate when or even if it was fixed. Does anyone have more up-to-date info on that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll to the end of the bug report.  It says:

> This was fixed in mustang b49 as 6306165.
>
> Posted Date : 2005-10-20 07:30:11.0

(Mustang was the project name for JDK 6.)